# How to create openTok sessionID and TokenID every time in android?

Tags: java, javascript, android

I am using Opentok for the purpose of video chatting and creating sessionId and tokenID from the Dashboard (Tokbox.com) . But I want to create sessionID and TokenID dynamically in android application so that only two user will share newly created sessionId and tokenID for video chatting and no third person can interfere in between them. 
Please Give me the way to do same ?

Comment: I have used opentok for video chatting but in my case server side opentok lib will generating the session id and token id. After that my app server was providing that one to the respective user.

Comment: that means I have to user Server side SDK, am I right?

Comment: Yes. But also check new lib provided by opentok.